# svcutil support for WS-Addressing and WS-Policy

Tags: svcutil.exe, ws-addressing

I'm using schema-first web service development approach by hand-coding WSDL/XSD and then feeding it to svcutil tool to generate .NET data and service contracts. I've tried to introduce WS-Addressing into my WSDL by including "UsingAddressing" element both directly into binding and as WS-Policy import. Policy import is ignored, but I get the following error, when "UsingAddress" is included directly into WSDL binding: "WSDL extension element "UsingAddressing" from namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl' was not handled".

According to MSDN, "UsingAddressing" element is supported by WCF (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996497.aspx), so is it so, that this element is not supported by svcutil?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this, I had the same problem trying to generate a proxy with svcutil. I had to generate the proxy via VS2017 and it worked.